# Chrome ignore injected debugger statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a malicious script that's injecting debugger statements to prevent me from debugging it. The script injects the debugger statement into the dom somehow thus not having any origin.

The only ways to prevent the debugger statement from running is either through black boxing or deactivating all breakpoints. Both methods do not cover this case.

I want to be able to debug DOM manipulations but ignore any other call to the debugger.

Comment: I would use Fiddler (or similar app) to replace "debugger" with "" in all incoming js files and inside script tags.

Comment: @wOxxOm For now I've made a copy of the malicious site and added a entry to my hosts file redirecting their domain to `127.0.0.1`. I think there should be a option in chrome allowing me to disable scripts from running the debugger statement..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [blackboxing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#blackbox) the script? While stepping through code, blackboxing just ignores the scripts that you specify. So it seems like that would prevent you from constantly pausing on the malicious debugger statements.

P.S. @MenzoWijmenga mentioned that deactivating all breakpoints doesn't work in this case, but for anyone else where that would be an OK solution see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624940/1669860).

Comment: Could you explain how this answers my question? The entire gist of my question is how to stop debugger statements when black boxing and pausing breakpoints are not an option.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the nuances of your situation. Such as the fact that the debugger statements get injected into the DOM and do not appear to have any origin (therefore you wouldn't be able to specify a particular script to blackbox).

Comment: Thanks for the response and too bad it doesnt fix my problem. Still haven't solved it.