# Chrome debugger paused even without breakpoints?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When inspecting this site, the scripts are always paused in the debugger even if there are no break points set, and if the the pause is un-paused, it again pauses itself.

What can be done?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J84eU.png

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the code so I guess there's a `debugger;` statement somewhere. Usually you can right-click on that line and choose to never stop there, otherwise see [Is it possible to avoid breaking on a debugger statement in Chrome?](//stackoverflow.com/a/53972086)

Answer (score 5):

To ignore all breakpoints (including `debugger` statements):

1. [Open DevTools](https://devtools.chrome.com/open).
2. Click **Deactivate Breakpoints**.

   [image: Deactivate Breakpoints]
3. Reload the page.

Comment: Also, the pause button can help. The pause button is the button immediately to the right of the button enclosed by your red circle. (The view of the button is hidden by the thickness of the red circle mark.)

Answer (score 0):

Open dev tools, go to the sources tab, and in the top right corner is a stop sign icon with the tooltip text 'Pause on Exceptions'. Make sure this is turned off.
Here's a screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have such situation quite often (maybe several times a month). After some time the issue goes away but so far I am failed to find out any deterministic workaround. This is very annoying. So, I will post workarounds here.
**Workaround 1.**
Opened the page in new browser tab. Opened source in the debugger. There appeared to be a breakpoint which was invisible on old tab. It was positioned couple line below than the debugger pause was happening. After removal the breakpoint the issue had gone.